# How to properly generate a form action for a POST request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-post, path-variables

I'm trying to generate an `action` for my Spring form and getting 400 Bad Request errors.

I generate the action using the active tabs index with the following JS `onsubmit`:

```
function getActionFromTab(form, prefix) {
    form.action = prefix + getActiveTab() + ".html";
}

function getActiveTab() {
    return $('.nav-tabs .active').index();
}
```

and used like so:

```
...
<form:form commandName="foo" cssClass="form-horizontal"
                        onsubmit="getActionFromTab(this, '/profile/')">
...
```

...which works fine as for setting the action when I swap out what's here for `return "/profile.html";` which is found in my controller along with the one that is failing:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addFoo(@ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo, Principal principal) {
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/profile/{index}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addBar(@ModelAttribute("bar") Bar bar, @PathVariable int index, 
        Principal principal) {
    ...
}
```

But when I append the index to the url it throws the 400 error.

I have other pages, controllers, and mappings using `@PathVariable` done the same way but they're not `POST` requests. What is the correct way to generate a form action and avoid the 400 Bad Request Error?

Comment: I guess you have defined the suffix .html in your view resolver. So profile.html is being solved by your Handlermethod. In your example you have mapping on /profile/{index} what results in /profile/1.html if index is 1. Is this desired?

Comment: @s.kwiotek - yes I've defined it. Yes, that's what was desired; is there something incorrect about that? It's the pattern I was using for detail pages and stuck with it.

Comment: Could you show whole implementation of your addBar Method?

Comment: @s.kwiotek, I can but it never gets called due to the 400 error; breakpoints are never triggered; do you still think it'd be helpful?

Comment: I could not reproduce it, my copy of your impl. is running fine tested with HttpRequester. How do you build up your Request, normally with command button or with Ajax?

Comment: @s.kwiotek, thanks for trying. I'm pretty sure it doesn't actually have anything to do with the creating of the url and more to do with the data relationships I have.

Comment: I guess there is something with your request (400:Bad Request). Maybe not with building Url, but with data or header that is send.

Comment: @s.kwiotek, yep, pretty certain it was due to a form input of `Date` type that was causing it. This is resolved but the solution doesn't answer the question and it may also be true that the above code is in fact a proper, or at least acceptable, way to generate an `action` dynamically. Thanks again for your attempts.